# .inputrc TAB not behaving as expected

Tags: bash, readline

I'm on a roll today, here's another question:

How come when I put these into `.inputrc`, they both do the same thing?

```
TAB: menu-complete
Shift-TAB: menu-complete-reverse
```

i.e. they both do whatever the last one says.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Readline doesn't know anything about a modifier called `Shift`, and quietly ignores unknown modifier names. Try `wibble-TAB`.

To bind an action to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, you need to find out what escape sequence your terminal sends. In bash, run `cat` and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. This will insert the escape sequence literally. It's likely that the first character will be an escape character, shown as `^[`; different terminals have different escape sequences, but common possibilities are `␛[Z` (i.e. escape, left bracket, capital Z) and `␛␉` (i.e. escape, tab). Bind the key appropriately in `~/.inputrc` (where `\e` means an escape character).

```
"\e\t": menu-complete-backward
"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward
```

Comment: Ah, `^[Z` worked for me (BASH); thanks for the detailed answer! :)

Comment: Do you press Enter before or after 'cat'?  Why is 'cat' needed?  I seem to get the same escape sequences without 'cat'.

Comment: @douglas.kramer Running `cat` avoids any bash binding. Usually bash has the same Ctrl+V binding to insert the next character literally so it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting Shift+Tab to bind to 'shell-expand-command'. I get:

`$ cat <Enter> <Shift+Tab>`
which displays
`^[[Z`

Do I always add `\e` ahead of the sequence I get from `Ctrl+V`?

Does this translate to:
`"\e^[[Z": shell-expand-command`

Comment: @dou Replace `^[` by `\e\`

Comment: Might want to use `cat -vet` in later model installs.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I had to use `"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward`

Comment: What to do if Shift+Tab produces no output at all in cat?

Comment: @Fopedush Configure your terminal to send something for Shift+Tab, if you can. How to do this is completely dependent on the terminal emulator.

Comment: Apparently my terminal emulator had a shortcut already bound to shift+tab and was thus not relaying the escape sequence to the terminal itself. After deleting the key binding, everything works as described. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

On Xubuntu 16.04, terminal: xfce4-terminal 0.6.3, shell: bash

For <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to work I had to use:

```
bind '"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward'
```

Comment: In `~/.bash_profile` use: `bind TAB:menu-complete` and `bind '"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward'` (note the usage of single and double quotes!).